# how do i enable my wireless connection?

Tags: wireless, internet-connection

I can't enable my wireless connection after i upgraded my ubuntu 10.04 LTS into ubuntu 11.10.  my WiFi works just fine on ubuntu 10.04.  I have an Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter from Atheros Communications Inc.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and add this

```
blacklist acer-wmi
```

or you might have to do the following:

```
sudo modprobe -rfv ath9k
sudo modprobe -v ath9k nohwcrypt=1
```

---

If that works you can make it permanent:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

Add the following line:

```
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1
```

Reboot.